# Why doesn't java document asymptotic complexity like C++ does?

Tags: java, c++

I notice that standard documentation of Java libraries (ie ArrayList<>.[add,remove,...] don't include method asymptotic complexities like their C++ equivalents do. This seems like it would greatly impede developing efficient programs in Java using standard libraries.. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Some things: [`ArrayList.add` is guaranteed to be amortized constant time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). [`List.sort` is guaranteed to be `O(n log n)` in comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). It looks like Java *does* give complexity guarantees. But it's certainly more obvious in C++, which probably has to do with culture

Comment: Eh? The Javadoc is *full* of asymptotic complexity guarantees. For example, the entire Collections package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The running times of java collection methods are not documented in the methods themselves, because they do not belong to specific collection classes, they belong to interfaces, like the `Collection` interface, or the `Map` interface, which are implementation-agnostic.

So, the `remove()` method may have a `O(1)` if the class implementing the interface is a linked list, or a `O(n)` if the class implementing the interface is an array-list; therefore, the interface can make no guarantees about the performance of the method.

However, if you look at the documentation of java's concrete collection classes themselves, (for example, `ArrayList`,) you will always find some comment explaining the general behavior of the class with regards to asymptotic complexity.  It is just that this information is not repeated in every single method of the class, because a) it is unnecessary, and b) in the vast majority of cases, java code accesses interfaces, not concrete classes, so the only kind of documentation that you can see about a collection method is the documentation provided by the interface, not by the class.

It would help if you told us precisely which C++ equivalents you are talking about, but I suspect that you are looking at concrete C++ classes, or templates, but not interfaces.  When a method is non-virtual, we know which class is implementing it, so we can document its asymptotic complexity. When the method is virtual, we cannot do such a thing.